# How might one create custom "Smart Folders" in Outlook 2011 Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook-2011, office-for-mac

As soon as was possible, I left Entourage in favor of Outlook 2011 Mac. I'm using Exchange 2010.

I seem to recall being able to create custom "Smart Folders" when I used Outlook on Windows, but can't seem to find a way to do it in Outlook 2011 on Mac. The closest I've seen was to use Filters on a folder, but that doesn't seem to include sub-folders, and I can't find a way to save it to come back to later.

What I would ultimately like is a single view that shows me anything that is flagged or unread, from any folder. I use server-side rules extensively to sort mail into different folders, so aggregating across all folders is important.

I accomplished this in Entourage by creating one saved search that showed flagged items from any folder, another that showed unread items from any folder, and then a third (which I would use as my primary view) that aggregated the contents of these other two custom views.

Anyone have any suggestions, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: outlook 2011 for mac hasn't been released to everyone yet, has it? it's only in rtm I think.

Comment: Volume licensing customers have access. :)

Comment: Outlook 2011 needs an "OR" operator for sure... biggest missing component in both rules and smart folder creation - BIG MISTAKE Microsoft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use raw queries. For flagged or unread mails:

```
(com_microsoft_outlook_flagged = 1) || (com_microsoft_outlook_unread = 1)
```

**Important note:** Do not use this folder with the "mark as read immediately" option, as seen here:

[image]

This results in a continuous *mark as read -- remove from view -- show next message -- mark as read* cycle, until everything is marked as read and you have no idea what you've now missed. Instead, I've switched to the 2nd option displayed that marks as read when you select a different message.

Answer (score 19):

There is a good description [on this site](http://www.michaellinenberger.com/myn-book/support/Outlook2011-is-here.html):

> 1. Click into the search field
> 2. A new ribbon called search should appear; click on it
> 3. Click Advanced and create your filters
> 4. Click Save; a new smart folder with the name untitled should appear
> 5. Double click the folder if you want to rename it

Comment: This gets me part of the way there -- I now have a smart folder that aggregates unread mail from all folders, and another that shows all flagged-for-follow-up mail... is there a way to combine them into one view? I don't see a way to use an **OR** operator when combining rules in the creation of a new smart folder, so that I could say Unread -OR- Flagged.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Microsoft couldn't make this more complicated... :/ This could be so easy like right-click on Smart Folders and pick New Smart Folder...